# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \alpha$

Tags: calculus, functions, uniform-convergence

> Let $f_n\to f$, uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ and let's assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f_n(x) = \alpha_n$ and $\alpha_n\to \alpha$. Show that: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \alpha$$

Now, the proof goes like this.

- Let $\varepsilon > 0$.
- We take $N_0$ such that $\sup |f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \varepsilon /3$ for all $n\ge N_0$.
- We take $N_1$ such that $|\alpha_n - \alpha| \le \varepsilon /3$ for all $n\ge N_1$.
- We take $N = \max(N_0,N_1)$
- Then, there's an $\color{red}{M>0}$ such that $\color{red}{|f_N(x)-\alpha_N(x)| \lt \varepsilon / 3}$, for all $\color{red}{x\ge M}$.

Therefore, for all $x\ge M$:

$$|f(x)-\alpha| \le |f(x)-f_n(x)| + |f_n(x)-\alpha_n| + |\alpha_n -\alpha| \le \varepsilon$$

Now, I don't fully understand the red part. Why there's such $M>0$?

Comment: That's from the definition of $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f_N(x) = \alpha_N$. The definition is probably phrased something like "for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $M_\varepsilon$ …". Substitute $\varepsilon/3$ for $\varepsilon$ there. And it must be $\alpha_N$, not $\alpha_N(x)$, it's a constant, not a function.

Comment: Yes, but you have to take into account the fact that $f_n(x)$ is an infinite series of functions. Couldn't it be that as $N$ grows, then $x$ must grow too in order to have $|f_n(x) - \alpha_n| \le \varepsilon / 3$?

Comment: But we look at only one fixed $N$ (which we chose according to a prescribed $\varepsilon > 0$). For every prescribed $\varepsilon > 0$ we first choose an appropriate $N$, then with that specific $N$, we choose an appropriate $M$ so that $f_N(x)$ approximates $\alpha_N$ to within $\varepsilon/3$ for $x\geqslant M$. Then do the triangle thing to see that $f(x)$ therefore approximates $\alpha$ to within $\varepsilon$ for $x\geqslant M$.

Comment: Oh I see now... Thank you @DanielFischer!